# Changing blade content tags in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am upgrading a project from Laravel 4.2 to 5.4 and I am wondering if there is a way to change blade's tags?

I have hundreds of places where I have used `{{{ $content }}}` to show unescaped html. If I am unable to change it, I need will to change all of them by hand to `{!! $content !!}`

I saw this saying that it has been removed https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17640

But surerly there's still a way around this?

**EDIT**

I found where I can change them in `BladeCompiler.php`. My next question, what is the difference between "regular echos" and "escaped echos"

```
/**
 * Array of opening and closing tags for raw echos.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $rawTags = ['{!!', '!!}'];

/**
 * Array of opening and closing tags for regular echos.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $contentTags = ['{{', '}}'];

/**
 * Array of opening and closing tags for escaped echos.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $escapedTags = ['{{{', '}}}'];
```

Comment: Why you are not using your IDE to help you with this, to replace {{{ to {!! and }}} to !!} in all places? This is the right way to do it.

Comment: I don't think phpstorm has a way to find and replace recursively otherwise I would

Comment: If any PHP has a feature, it will be PHPStorm. However a replace function is very very common, notepad++ etc also can do this.

Comment: @BenShepherd have you tried [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html)?

Comment: @MustafaEhsan I went through all the files manually and replaced the ones I needed. I needed to check I wasn't vulnerable to XSS so I thought doing it manually would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in the comments you use PHPStorm. You can simply replace (*ctrl + shift + R*)

```
{{{ to {!!
```

and

```
}}} to !!}
```

or in 1 replace (little gain)
turn on regex

```
\{\{\{([^}]+)\}\}\} to {!!$1!!}
```

[image]